# IndexError: list index out of range exeption in python

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I try to write an algorithm in python, and i dont understand why its out of range.I am realy dont understand where is the problem
This is my code

```
B = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = 4


def b(m, i):
    if m % 2 == 0 and m > 2:
        if i < m - 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return m - 2
    else:
        return m - 1


def PERM(m):
    if m == 1:
        print(P)
    else:
        for i in range(0, m):
            PERM(m - 1)
            if i < m:
                k = P[m]
                P[m] = P[b(m, i)]
                P[b(m, i)] = k


PERM(n)
```

Comment: What is the size of P? where is it define? Can you please provide these details in the question?

Answer (score 1):

in for i in range(0, m):, the loop is iterting from 0 to 4 which is total of 5 index so better you change the n = 4 to n = 3, hope this help :)